# Select where day not in between of daytime and End_date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following data:

Table1:

```
Code   code_id   day
F23    123df     16 Jul 2016
F23    123df     17 Jul 2016
F23    123df     18 Jul 2016
F23    123df     19 Jul 2016
F23    123df     20 Jul 2016
F24    124df     16 Jul 2016
F24    124df     17 Jul 2016
F24    124df     18 Jul 2016
F24    124df     19 Jul 2016
F24    124df     20 Jul 2016
```

Table2:

```
Code   code_id   status     daytime                 End_date
F23    123df     down      16 Jul 2016 06:00 am    18 Jul 2016 08:00 pm
F23    123df     down      19 Jul 2016 05:00 am    21 Jul 2016 03:45 pm
F23    123df     down      23 Jul 2016 02:40 am
```

I need to select data from table1 where day not in between of daytime and End_date from table2 and if table1 day (like '16 Jul 2016' is the same day as '16 Jul 2016 06:00' from table2) is like table2 day from daytime or End_date fields then it still has to select data for this day. In case of End_date is null then it has to be sysdate - nvl(End_date,sysdate).

For example when select for day = '16 Jul 2016' from table1 it has to be:

```
F23    123df     16 Jul 2016
F24    124df     16 Jul 2016
```

But when select for '17 Jul 2016' then it has to be:

```
F24    124df     17 Jul 2016
```

When select for '18 Jul 2016' it has to be:

```
F23    123df     18 Jul 2016
F24    124df     18 Jul 2016
```

thanks,
S

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   table2 x
         WHERE  t.code                          =  x.code
         AND    t.code_id                       =  x.code_id
         AND    t.day                           >= x.daytime
         AND    t.day + INTERVAL '86399' SECOND <= x.end_date
       );
```